# Is the same overcurrent relay used for both phase-to-phase faults and 3-phase faults?

Tags: relay, short-circuit, power-grid, fault

In MV grid with no distributed generators,  50-51 overcurrent relays are used to detect both phase to phase faults anf 3-phase faults.

In Italy, time independent characteristics are used inside these relays. Since the short circuit current in the two case is not so different, generally speaking, is the same relay used for both faults or just one for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, phase-overcurrent.  That said, you could use a negative sequence overcurrent for the ph-ph faults.  Just learn how to coordinate it properly…not always simple as stacking curves.

Comment: I was sure I would receive an answer by you :D Thank you! But I didn't understand what do you mean with ''yes'', it is is related to the fact that the same relay is used for both faults in the grid or not

Comment: Yes, a phase time-overcurrent is used for both 3ph and ph-ph fault protection.  Same relay element.  The ph-ph fault will be smaller than 3ph fault by root 3 divided by 2.

Comment: Also the time-independent characteristic is usually the same? If yes, since the phase-to-phase current is lower, the time-independent characteristic is designed on the phase to phase fault (minimum trip, otherwise if they designed it for the 3-phase one only, when there is a phase to phase fault the relay might not trip) right?

Comment: What do you mean by the “time-independent” characteristic? Do you mean an overcurrent that trips instantaneously (no delay)?

Comment: no, the time-independent characteristics are those with steps, and they would trip only if a predefined current is flowing through the relay. Then there are also time-dependent relays like inverse, very inverse, ecc.. which are not characterized by steps, but are curves which may trips not if a predefined current will flow at all, but also if that current will flow for a certain period. This is not the exact definition because also time independent relays would trip only if the predefined threshold current will flow for a certain time, but this is true just of 1 to 3 current threshold usually.

Comment: I see.  What you are calling "time-independent" is what I would call "definite time" overcurrent.  It would operate at a definite time (e.g. 45 cycles) if current above pickup.

Comment: yes exactly! You caught it! So, is the definite time characteristic used the same (and so do we have only one relay on the grid with one definite time characteristic for both phase to phase and 3 phase faults?)?

Comment: When overcurrent protection is used, I would expect the same element to provide both 3PH and PH-PH fault protection.